# CefSharp.Winforms close tab by javascript which opened in another thread

Tags: javascript, c#, multithreading, chromium-embedded, cefsharp

My previous question:
[CefSharp.Winforms close tab by javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32583742/cefsharp-winforms-close-tab-by-javascript/)

I've implemented the interface ILifeSpanHandler to create a new tab and close it by javascript. However, the tabs opened by javascript can not be closed by javascript, it lead to closing all tabs, programs and throw a null references exception. I tried to create a new tab in another thread, and similar errors have occurred, while the tabs created by the main thread can be normally closed by window.close javascript. I realize that creating a new tab by javascript also be implemented in a particular thread. Thus, the closure by javascript of chromium webbrowser created in another thread will cause errors. How can I handle it?

Comment: Marshal your tab creation back onto the `UI` thread.

Comment: How do I marshal tab creation back onto UI thread? Please guid me

Comment: You should use Control.BeginInvoke: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0b1bf3y3(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 0):

I have extended the `CefSharp.WinForms.Example` project to demo the new `OnOpenUrlFromTab` feature.

See relevant commit at
https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/commit/fff080869394bd6604125a1fdd7a592eaa8d9ae7#diff-2d452d0f740a396ca039eaeafed80b47R30